# Is it possible to add Function.caller support to Rhino?

Tags: java, javascript, rhino

Looking at it, Rhino doesn't support the `caller` property for functions - does anyone know if there is a branch that allows this, even if just in interpreter mode?

If not, does anyone have any general ideas about how this might be added?

Answer (score 0):

Never heard about `Function.prototype.caller` in javascript, but there's `arguments.callee.caller`, which is really unsupported in Rhino according to the Internet;

If you need to get stack traces, there's an idea for solution:
http://groups.google.com/group/mozilla.dev.tech.js-engine.rhino/browse_thread/thread/a8db6d5c4c729f0e/a5f717c02af610ea?pli=1

Comment: `arguments.callee` just gives you a reference to the current function - therefore `arguments.callee.caller` is getting the `caller` property of the current function.

Comment: You can get stack traces in Rhino via `stack` property of the JS error, anyway so I think that's ok.

Comment: `arguments.callee.caller` gets parent-scope function.
`(function foo() { return (function bar() { return arguments.callee.caller.name) })() })() -> foo`

Comment: It gets a reference to the function from which it was invoked - which is not necessarily its parent-scope.