# In Javascript, how can I check if a function is in strict mode *without changing the function*?

Tags: javascript, strict

I want to write a test suite to ensure some given functions are using strict mode. There are many of them, and manually inspecting them seems like a chore.

[An answer in a similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11531511/is-it-possible-to-tell-whether-a-function-is-in-strict-mode-or-not) uses a regex on the function's definition to check. However, I believe this will misdetect situations where the function being tested is inside a function with "use strict" or a file-level "use strict" declaration. The answer says that "use strict" is prepended, but in my environment (Mozilla Rhino), this is not the case:

```
$ cat strict_sub.js
"use strict";
var strict_function = function() {
    not_a_real_global = "foo";
};

print(strict_function);
$ rhino strict_sub.js 

function () {
    not_a_real_global = "foo";
}
```

I feel like the answer is "no", but is there no way to introspect a function to see if it was parsed and found to be strict mode?

Update: One method suggest by @Amy was to parse the function's source to figure it out. This works if the *function* has a use-strict declaration (although it's tedious), but not if it the strict-mode is propagation from, say, Program-level; in that case, we have to walk up the AST to the Program level and check *that* for `use strict`. To make this robust, we'd have to implement all the rules for `use strict`-propagation, which the interpreter already has somewhere.

(Tested in SpiderMonkey:

```
function f() {
  "use strict";
}
var fast1 = Reflect.parse(f.toString());

var first_line = fast1.body[0].body.body[0].expression;

print(first_line.type === 'Literal' && first_line.value === 'use strict'); //true
```

)

Comment: I usualy use this: var isStrict = (function() { return !this; })(); console.log(isStrict);

Comment: @Shakawkaw: but that needs be run inside the function to be tested. I need to test it externally.

Comment: *"is there no way to introspect a function to see if it was parsed and found to be strict mode"* No.

Comment: Not without parsing it yourself (such as with the Spidermonkey Parser API) and checking the resulting AST, no.

Comment: @Amy: I tried parsing with Spidermonkey, but it really only tells me that (for example) there is a string literal there. If there's a file-level strict, I would have to check for that myself as well.

Comment: Right.  You would have to parse the whole file.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Strict mode functions do have a ["poisoned" `.caller` and `.arguments` properties](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-addrestrictedfunctionproperties) (also [ES5](http://es5.github.io/#x13.2), [extra](http://es5.github.io/#x15.3.5.4)), so you can test that:

```
function isStrict(fn) {
    if (typeof fn != "function")
        throw new TypeError("expected function");
    try {
        fn.caller; // expected to throw
        return false;
    } catch(e) {
        return true;
    }
}
```

Comment: Spec source would be useful.

Comment: Oh dang, I confused [Function `.caller`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/caller) with the **`arguments` object** which does have these poisoned properties (@BenAston: [ES5](http://es5.github.io/#x10.6), [ES6](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-arguments-exotic-objects))

Comment: @BenAston: Oh, I just stumbled across it: strict mode function objects actually do have poisoned properties as well

Comment: I'm just not sure whether this still works with ES6, where these poisoned properties seem to be inherited from `Function.prototype`, so that even sloppy mode functions may have them if an environment does not create non-standard own properties for them.

Comment: Not sure I'm totally following, but I implemented your function and made some tests. In Spidermonkey, works well. In Rhino, seems like [function.caller is not implemented](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8986828/is-it-possible-to-add-function-caller-support-to-rhino) :( Even though your answer doesn't work in Rhino, I'd argue it's Rhino that's broken.

Comment: @nfirvine: This function doesn't rely on the `.caller` support for functions. It relies on the ES5 spec requiring that strict mode functions *don't implement* it, and even more, that it must throw. Did you test in Rhino? Does Rhino follow ES5 or ES6?